# Nested function calls in Bash

Tags: bash, function

Right now, I'm trying to nest one bash function call inside another function call (so that the output of one function is used as the input for another function). Is it possible to nest function calls in bash, as I'm trying to do here?

First, I defined these two functions:

```
returnSomething()
{
    return 5;
}

funky ()
{
  echo $1;
}
```

Then, I tried to use the output of one function as the input for the other function. 
However, this next statement doesn't print the output of `returnSomething`. Instead, it prints nothing at all.

```
funky $returnSomething; #Now I'm trying to use the output of returnSomething as the input for funky.
```

Comment: Try just `funky returnSomething`. `$returnSomething` is a variable, not a call to the function.

Comment: [see this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions)

Comment: `funky $(returnSomething)`

Comment: @Kevin This doesn't seem to make any difference: it still prints nothing at all.

Comment: @fedorqui In that case, it would only print the string `returnSomething` to the console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two problems. One is that `return` does not set the *output* of a function, but rather its *exit status* (zero for success, nonzero for failure). For example, `echo foo` will *output* `foo` (plus a newline), but has an *exit status* of `0`. To control output, use `echo` or `printf`:

```
function returnSomething ()     # should actually be outputSomething
{
    echo 5
}
```

The other problem is that `$returnSomething` (or `${returnSomething}`) gives the value of a variable named `returnSomething`:

```
x=5          # sets the variable x
echo "$x"    # outputs 5
```

To capture the output of a command, use the notation `$(...)` (or `` `...` ``, but the latter is trickier). So:

```
function funky ()
{
    echo "$( "$1" )"
}
funky returnSomething    # prints 5
```

or just:

```
function funky ()
{
    "$1"          # runs argument as a command
}
funky returnSomething    # prints 5
```

By contrast, if you do want to capture the exit status of a command, use the special shell parameter `?` (which is set to the exit status of a command when it completes):

```
function returnSomething ()
{
    return 5
}
function funky ()
{
    "$1"          # runs argument as a command
    echo "$?"     # prints its exit status
}
funky returnSomething    # prints 5
```

Comment: I still haven't figured out how to nest one function call (with parameters) inside another function call. For example, `(sampleFunction2 (sampleFunction1 "Parameter for sample function 1"))` produces `syntax error near unexpected token sampleFunction1'`. Is it possible to make nested function calls like this one?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking; Bash commands support a greater variety of possible interactions than functions in other languages, so there are multiple ways to combine them that could all be called "nesting". My best guess is, maybe you want the *output* of the command `sampleFunction1 "Parameter for sample function 1"` to be captured (instead of going to the console, as it normally would), and you want that output to be passed as an *argument* (a parameter) to the function `sampleFunction2`. Is that right? If so, you can write *(continued)*

Comment: *(continued)* `sampleFunction2 "$(sampleFunction1 "Parameter for sample function 1")"`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was asking. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I still haven't figured out function nesting for functions that take more than one parameter: for example,`add "$(add ""$(add "3 2")" "$(add "4 7")"")"`. This function is supposed to take the output of two nested function calls as its parameters, but it doesn't appear to be syntactically correct. I haven't found any Bash documentation that describes nested function calls in detail, so I'm still confused by this.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: I think you're confused about how double-quotes work in Bash. `foo bar baz` calls the program `foo` with two arguments (`bar` and `baz`), whereas `foo "bar baz"` calls it with only one argument (`bar baz`). If I understand correctly that your `add` function expects two integer arguments prints their sum, and you want to compute the sum of four integers, then you can write: `add "$(add 3 2)" "$(add 4 7)"`.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: By the way, all of this is explained in detail in the *Bash Reference Manual*; see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution.

Comment: It appears that the double-quotes aren't even necessary here: if `add` is a function that returns the sum of two numbers, then `echo $(add $(add 3 2) $(add 4 7))` will print the sum of all of these numbers.

Comment: Also, I think you should add this information to the answer itself, since it's possible that all of these these comments will be deleted by Stack Overflow's moderators.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Regarding double-quotes: it's always a good idea to wrap expansions such as `$(...)` in double-quotes, so that even if they misbehave and output something different than you expect, you can at least be sure they'll end up as the right number of parameters. (Consider something like `cp foo.txt bar.txt $(baz)`, which is supposed to copy `foo.txt` and `bar.txt` into the directory that `baz` says to -- but if `baz` (say) errors out and doesn't print any directory at all, then this will overwrite `bar.txt` with a copy of `foo.txt`.)

Comment: Regarding `echo`, "returns": Please, I keep trying to tell you. `add` is not a function that *returns* the sum of two numbers, it's a function that *prints* the sum of two numbers. `echo $(add ...)` is completely redundant; you just want `add "$(add 3 2)" "$(add 4 7)"`, without `echo`.

Comment: @ruakh, Anderson is right. You should absolutely add your comments into the answer body. This info was really helpful for me and obviously will be for others.

Answer (score 3):

Bash substitutes `$(command)` with the output of `command`, so you can use `funky $(returnSomething)` to pass `funky` the output of `returnSomething`.  However, it looks like you're misunderstanding `return` in bash; the return value is a number that indicates whether the call was successful. The way to get the return status of the last process in bash is `$?`:

```
returnSomething
funky $?
```

Comment: Does this mean that it's basically impossible for a function in Bash to return any kind of non-integer value?

Comment: Yes, you have to print it and capture the output, or set a variable (though there are a number of gotchas around that)

Comment: What are those "gotchas", specifically?

Comment: If you put a call in a subshell (either as part of a pipe, an explicit subshell, or a `$(...)` subshell), it won't affect the caller's environment.  This especially gets people in loops. You have to declare the variable before the function.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function foo() { echo one two three; }
function bar() { echo foo #1: $1 }
bar $( foo ) # ==> foo #1: one
```

The above has problem, thanks to Anderson for pointing it out. Here is an update:

```
function foo() { echo one two three; }
function bar() { echo foo $1; }
bar $( foo )
```