# Bash - Return value from subscript to parent script

Tags: bash

I have two Bash scripts. The parent scripts calls the subscript to perform some actions and return a value. How can I return a value from the subscript to the parent script? Adding a `return` in the subscript and catching the value in the parent did not work.

Comment: Take a look at this answer from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16325765/1983854 - it may help a lot

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I am assuming these scripts are running in two different processes, i.e. you are not "sourcing" one of them.

It depends on what you want to return.  If you wish only to return an exit code between 0 and 255 then:

```bash
# Child (for example: 'child_script')
exit 42
```

```bash
# Parent
child_script
retn_code=$?
```

If you wish to return a text string, then you will have to do that through stdout (or a file).  There are several ways of capturing that, the simplest is:

```bash
# Child (for example: 'child_script')
echo "some text value"
```

```bash
# Parent
retn_value=$(child_script)
```

Comment: Does the echo method return everything echo'd by the child script or just the last line?

Comment: @AakilFernandes: in this case, `echo` writes the line given to it: "some text value" in the example.  However, the parent is capturing all the standard output from the child, whether it came from an `echo` or not.  That could be multiple lines separated by newlines `$'\n'`

Comment: @cdarke What if i just want the last line to be captured by the parent?

Comment: @SaltukKezer you can use tail -1 to get the last line

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to return a text value from a child script using a temporary file. Create a tmp file in the parent_script and pass it to the child_script.  I prefer this way over parsing output from the script

Parent

```
#!/bin/bash
# parent_script
text_from_child_script=`/bin/mktemp`
child_script -l $text_from_child_script
value_from_child=`cat $text_from_child_script`
echo "Child value returned \"$value_from_child\""
rm -f $text_from_child_script
exit 0
```

Child

```
#!/bin/bash
# child_script
# process -l parm for tmp file

while getopts "l:" OPT
do
    case $OPT in
      l) answer_file="${OPTARG}"
         ;;
    esac
done

read -p "What is your name? " name

echo $name > $answer_file

exit 0
```

Answer (score -3):

return a value from the subscript and check the variable $? which contain the return value

Comment: "Return" is ambiguous here, as the `return` statement can only be used to return from a function, not a script. To be precise, you need to use the `exit` statement to return from the script.

Comment: @chepner: actually `return` can also be used from a "sourced" file ( `.` or `source` command), but is that then a script?

Comment: Ah, tricky. I guess the right answer then is "use `return` or `exit` as appropriate".