# csh: How to pass a variable from a subscript to a parent script

Tags: csh

I want to pass a variable which I set in a subscript to the parent script. I want to do that either as a function or just by "echo"ing the variable:

parent.sh

```
#!/bin/csh
enter code here
set VAR_2_CHILD_1 = myName
set VAR_2_CHILD_2 = MAIN_PATH/output.txt

$MAIN_PATH/child.sh $VAR_2_CHILD_1 $VAR_2_CHILD_2
```

child.sh

```
#!/bin/csh

if ($1 =~ *something*) then
    set NAME_SL     =  False
    set SUBDIRID    =  True
    echo $1 $SUBIDDIR       >> $2
endif

echo $NAME_SL $SUBDIRID
```

or:

```
#!/bin/csh

function pass_var() {

if ($1 =~ *something*) then
    set NAME_SL     =  False
    set SUBDIRID    =  True
    echo $1 $SUBIDDIR       >> $2
endif

return $NAME_SL $SUBDIRID
}
```

In the later case I do not know how to call the function in the parent.sh

In general the subscript should choose between option according to $VAR_2_CHILD_1 and VAR_2_CHILD_2 and returning some string variable $NAME_SL and $SUBDIRID. I do not how to do that.

I also read other questions here like: [Bash - Return value from subscript to parent script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338086/bash-return-value-from-subscript-to-parent-script) but I could not find anything which works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh!  You gladden my heart.  Wrote csh for a 10 year period (using csh, sed, awk, and pipes).  Just checked my archive: 650 scripts and 51000 lines.  Then, I discovered perl and switched everything.  Current perl is 770 files and 206,000 lines.

Anyway, a few things.  csh doesn't have functions, so you'll need to use child.sh.  (Please use .csh or no suffix--bash gets far too much attention as it is :-)

Note that csh *does* have aliases.  csh aliases are more powerful than bash aliases because they can take argument lists.  You can get the effect of a multiline script using `;` but it's limiting.

The parent can capture child output [either script or alias] via the `virgule` operator:

```
#!/bin/csh
# enter code here
set VAR_2_CHILD_1 = myName
set VAR_2_CHILD_2 = MAIN_PATH/output.txt

set result=(`$MAIN_PATH/child.sh $VAR_2_CHILD_1 $VAR_2_CHILD_2`)
set NAME_SL="$result[1]"
set SUBDIRNAME="$result[2]"
```

The parentheses around the child call are because the child is returning two words, so you need an array to capture them [if you want to manipulate them independently]

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply and help! It is working perfectly :-) !

Comment: @firefly2517 Thanks for your politeness.  My last 24 hours: hecklers in comments.  They're wrong--my mother would _never_ do _that_ :-).  And one, where an OP had a segfaulting program.  We were debugging it in realtime with comments:  try this, what result?, try this ...  Worked with OP for 2 hours.  Heckler hammered OP and OP withdrew the [+3] question [with 25 helpful comments]: I was about 15 min away from the solution.  BTW, how did you decide to use csh?  Was popular long time ago, now "It's a bash, bash, bash, bash world" (bash==mad) Even with perl, csh is still my login shell.

Comment: Life brought me to csh ;-), I just slipped into it but I like it. Somebody was showing me how to use .sh-files to configure my python programme. He is using csh and C, I am using csh and Python 2.7.10 now. Maybe I should switch to something more fancy, but I believe in simplicity! And it is working fine (at least sometimes ;-) )!