# Bash how to return value from subscript to main script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following script saved into a `menu.sh` file.

```
declare -a menu=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Option 4" "Option 5" "Option 6")
cur=0

draw_menu() {
    for i in "${menu[@]}"; do
        if [[ ${menu[$cur]} == $i ]]; then
            tput setaf 2; echo " > $i"; tput sgr0
        else
            echo "   $i";
        fi
    done
}

clear_menu()  {
    for i in "${menu[@]}"; do tput cuu1; done
    tput ed
}

# Draw initial Menu
draw_menu
while read -sn1 key; do # 1 char (not delimiter), silent
    # Check for enter/space
    if [[ "$key" == "" ]]; then break; fi

    # catch multi-char special key sequences
    read -sn1 -t 0.001 k1; read -sn1 -t 0.001 k2; read -sn1 -t 0.001 k3
    key+=${k1}${k2}${k3}

    case "$key" in
        # cursor up, left: previous item
        i|j|$'\e[A'|$'\e0A'|$'\e[D'|$'\e0D') ((cur > 0)) && ((cur--));;
        # cursor down, right: next item
        k|l|$'\e[B'|$'\e0B'|$'\e[C'|$'\e0C') ((cur < ${#menu[@]}-1)) && ((cur++));;
        # home: first item
        $'\e[1~'|$'\e0H'|$'\e[H')  cur=0;;
        # end: last item
        $'\e[4~'|$'\e0F'|$'\e[F') ((cur=${#menu[@]}-1));;
         # q, carriage return: quit
        q|''|$'\e')echo "Aborted." && exit;;
    esac
    # Redraw menu
    clear_menu
    draw_menu
done

echo "Selected item $cur: ${menu[$cur]}";
```

I now have a second `main.sh` where i call the `menu.sh` file like this: `./menu.sh` (they are in the same directory). How can i get the output of the `menu.sh` from the `main.sh`?
I can't get the echo to the standard output by piping or redirecting for some reason. Accessing it via $() also doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for all helpt!

Comment: what do you mean by 'get the output'? are you trying to capture the `menu.sh` output into a variable? something else?  fwiw, assuming the only contents of `main.sh` is `./menu.sh` ... the script works for me, ie, running `main.sh` from the command line displays the menu in my window (aka stdout)

Comment: Is any of the `tput` and key reading magic relevant, or can you remove that and still show the problem you're encountering ([mcve])?

Comment: @BenjaminW.I actually copied the code from here: https://www.bughunter2k.de/blog/cursor-controlled-selectmenu-in-bash.

Comment: @markp-fuso I just want to get access to the selected element from my main.sh (So basically want to have the output of the last echo accesible from `main.sh`). If i do something like `val=$(./menu.sh)` then the menu isn't shown in the main anymore. I want access to the last line because i want to further process it from the main script.
Is there another solution except for passing a file param to the subscript to save the "return" value into?

Comment: `val=$(./menu.sh)` (obvously) redirects stdout into the ariable `val` hence the reason your stdout 'disappears' ("Duh, Mark!" ?); while there's probably a way to redirect 'some' of stdout to a variable, the addition of `tput` calls and specialized cursor codes is going to add more complexity to the mix; at this point the provided script is (somewhat) complex and (imo) detracts from the true issue which is ... ?? *what* ?? ... you want to access the last line of the displayed menu?  at this point I'm not sure what it is you're trying to accomplish ....

Comment: I'd suggest reviewing [Hot to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then come back and update the question; in particular reduce `menu.sh` to a minimum set of code that generates the desired output, then tell us what part of this output you want 'redirected' to `main.sh`; some idea of what you want to so with the redirected data would also help (eg, store in variable? store in array? something else)? once you get something working for the minimal case then you can proceed to figuring out how to apply to your actual code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash - Return value from subscript to parent script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338086/bash-return-value-from-subscript-to-parent-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use another file to store the result.

1. In your main.sh, come up with a temp file name.
   Supply this temp file name to menu.sh
2. Add some handling in menu.sh to ensure that this file is supplied before going on.
   Change the result of menu.sh to write to the temp file
3. Back in main.sh, read the results from the temp file.
   Then get rid of the file

So, here is main.sh

```
RESULTS_FILE=results.`date +%s`.txt
./menu.sh $RESULTS_FILE
RESULTS=`cat $RESULTS_FILE`
echo "Got results:"
echo $RESULTS
rm $RESULTS_FILE
```

And then here is how you'd modify menu.sh

At the top

```
if [ "$1" == "" ] ; then 
    exit "You need to supply a temp file path"
fi
RESULTS_FILE=$1
```

At the bottom of menu.sh, change the last line to write to the file:

```
echo "Selected item $cur: ${menu[$cur]}" > $RESULTS_FILE
```

Comment: Thank your for your help, worked like a charm