# Bash Nested Private Functions

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a custom Mac Terminal command, `start`, In Terminal, my intent is to write `$ start func1 subfunc myText`, where `func` is a function in the start.sh file and `subfunc` is a function only in `func` that can only be called from in `func`. So `$ start subfunc myText` wouldn't be possible. I see that its possible to pass a function from another ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325548/nested-function-calls-in-bash)), but only when both are in the outer scope of the start.sh file.

Basically:

start.sh:

```
function func(){
  function subfunc(){
    echo $1
  }
}
```

and then in Terminal:
`$ start func subfunc Hey` prints Hey

Comment: I don't think bash has nested function scopes like this.

Comment: What is it supposed to achieve? Even if it works (it doesn't), Anyone who can't do `start subfunc myText` can still do `start func subfunc Hey` do still call `subfunc` anyway. What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: This feels like similar functionality to like an aws console command? I don't think bash is the right place to write this though. If you did, I think you would need to catch those arguments to variables and then perform logic based on what is in those variables `if [$command = "func"]` `if [ $subcommand = "subfunc"]` sort of thing... IT may help if you explained what you are trying to achieve though since it's not clear from your very not-working code.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used bash before and couldn't find great documentation for this. I was trying to create a custom hierarchy of commands to do something like nodecontroller nodestart node1 start, or something with a hierarchy of commands like this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the functions, not only declare them:

```
func() {
   subfunc() {
      echo "$1"
   }
   "$@"
}
"$@"
```

However functions have no scopes, so once you declare the function inside another function it overwrites the previous declaration. So I would advise so to make each function and sub-function name unique.

```
f() {
  f() {
    echo in
  }
  echo out
}

f // will print 'out'
f // will print 'in'
```

Note that using `function name() {}` is accepted, but [not really valid](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). Use `name() { }`, as `function name {}` is not specified by posix.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need nested functions for this. I think this is an argument parsing problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

start() {
    case $1 in 
        func) shift; do_func "$@" ;;
        *) echo "unknown subcommand"; exit 1 ;;
    esac
}

do_func() {
    case $1 in
        subfunc) shift; do_subfunc "$@" ;;
        *) echo "unknown sub-subcommand"; exit 1 ;;
    esac
}

do_subfunc() {
    echo "$1"
}

start "$@"
```

Then

```
$ ./start func foo
unknown sub-subcommand
$ ./start func subfunc 'hello world'
hello world
```